# What does this code mean? OpenCV

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

May I know what does x represent? Does the content inside of () represent a pointer? then the [] is the element of the array?

```
 x = (df_dx->imageData+i*df_dx->widthStep)[j];
```

why doesnt it work if i put it this way?

```
 x=df_dx[2][j];
```

Does the

```
->imageData
```

give the pixel value of the image? The full code is below. THanks

```
float x;
IplImage*df_dx = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(grayimg),IPL_DEPTH_16S,1); 


for(int i=0;i=grayimg->height;i++)
{
for(int j=0;grayimg->width;j++)
{

x = (df_dx->imageData+i*df_dx->widthStep)[j]; 
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, x is the grayscale float pixel data at (j, i)

Comment: @holtavolt, thanks. I updated the question. Why doesn't it work if x=(df_dx)[j]?

Comment: @holtavolt, ignore my last question. wait... (j,i)? why not (i,j)?

Comment: The matrix is row-major, with i as the row index, and j as the column.  You might want to review the classes here: http://opencv.jp/opencv-2svn_org/cpp/core_basic_structures.html

Comment: For the same reason 2d arrays are always accessed with [y][x] rather than [x][y] - cache hits. This way ( [y][x] ), pixels next to each other on screen are next to each other in memory, rather than separated by the number of bytes required to represent a single row of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answers:

- `x` is the element on row j, column i of the matrix `df_dx`
- `df_dx->imageData` returns a pointer to the first element of the array (top-left)

Accessing matrix elements in such a way is actually quite common for 2d matrices stored in memory as flat one-dimensional arrays (see e.g. [GSL matrix accesses](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Accessing-matrix-elements.html#Accessing-matrix-elements) for a similar example with another library; see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505917/accessing-array-elements) for a similar question).

Storing a matrix as an array of arrays (i.e. using `[][]` for access) is definitely manageable, and many people chose to use this representation, but there are [reasons](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html) why one would prefer a flat layout in memory.

Comment: correct me if i m wrong. Let's say the (df_dx->imageData+i*df_dx->widthStep) gives a value of 5. 
So x=df_dx[5][j]?

Comment: No, `df_dx->imageData` is a pointer to the top-left element (beginning of the matrix), `df_dx->widthStep` is the number of rows in your matrix, so `(df_dx->imageData+i*df_dx->widthStep)` is a **pointer** to the `i`th column. If `*(df_dx->imageData+i*df_dx->widthStep)` is 5 (note the indirection), then `df_dx[0][i]==5`.

Comment: is the 0 in   df_dx[0][i]=5 indicate the j=0 during it's initial loop?

Comment: The 0 indicates the first element of the column, which is also the element pointed by the pointer to the `i`th column (as any array pointer).